# REST api not calling on the navigation

Tags: c#, javascript, knockout.js, durandal

HI i have the following code in my js file . im using drundal  framework for the file upload application using REST api . in that `http://localhost:49589/api/files` it will give the list of files stored in DB.

```
var Value = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.js = $.getJSON("http://localhost:49589/api/files", function (result) {
                self.Value(result);

            });
```

and the view has the following code

```
<table  data-bind="foreach: Value">
             <tr>
                 <td data-bind=" text: ID "></td>

             <td data-bind=" text: Name "> </td>
             <td data-bind=" text: Type "> </td>
            <td data-bind=" text: Size "> </td>

             </tr>


        </table>
```

once i upload a file im getting success alert and it is added in the DB . but if i navigate to the home page the newly added file details are not included . but if i close my application and restart it im getting the newly added file info .  i know this happens because while im navigating to the home page the `http://localhost:49589/api/files` it is not called . is there any way to rerender the home page while navigating

Comment: `var Value` and `self.Value` are not referring to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are calling your API in your activate function.

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (http, app, ko) {
return {
    Value: ko.observableArray([]),
    activate: function () {
        var that = this;
        return http.get('http://yourservice.com', { format: 'json' }, 'jsoncallback').then(function (response) {
            that.Value= response;
        });
    }
}
});
```